# implement post url in IFrame

Tags: javascript, iframe

How can I make a POST request to some URL (see my code below) in Javascript ?

My code so far doesn't work and I actually need to put it into an **iFrame** (having its with and height set to 0) to prevent the main page to reload.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $.post(
           "http://control.msg91.com/api/sendotp.php?otp_length=4&authkey=xxx&message=Your OTP is ##OTP##&sender=OTPSMS&mobile=xxx&otp_expiry=2"
           , function(data){
                 alert(data);
           });
     });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use an iframe, then do not use XMLHttpRequest (NB `$.post` is a jQuery that wraps around XMLHttpRequest).

Create a `<form>`. Set its `action` to the URL. It's `method` to `POST` and its `target` to the ID of the `<iframe>`.

Put the data in that form. Then submit it.

If you want to do this entirely with JavaScript, then you can create the form using DOM and with entirely hidden inputs so that nothing shows up in the existing page. Ensure that you append the form to the document as some browsers will not let you submit forms that aren't part of the document.

---

That said, since you want an iframe with no dimensions, it seems odd to want to use an iframe at all.

You might be trying to work around CORS limitations, but you should be able to use the code you are using to make a request successfully. You just won't be able to tell if it was successful or not (because the restrictions are on reading the response). If you used an iframe, you would have the same limitations.

If you want to suppress the error message that is shown in the console, you could use `fetch` with `mode: "no-cors"`. You still wouldn't be able to read the response though.

Comment: why should he not use `Ajax`

Comment: @messerbill — Because they explicitly asked to use an iframe, which is a different approach.

Comment: If the `Ajax` is called inside that Iframe that won't result in any problems - but due to i forgot that iframe i vote this up....but please comment why you downvoted the answer next time (if you were the one who voted my answer down) :)

Comment: thx guys, my approach is to send verification code to the users through the  url if i set the url without iframe the page will reload or another tabs will opens to get url parameter data so i thought the iframe will be the best fit for that i already warpping the input in form but it's a signup for so the action of that form is to get user data

Comment: <form action="http://control.msg91.com/api/sendotp.php?otp_length=4&authkey=195130AZjpYkgD5a69d7f6&message=Your OTP is ##OTP##&sender=OTPSMS&mobile=966592376048&otp_expiry=2" method="post">
       <iframe id="framee" name="theFrame"></iframe>
       <input type="submit" value="test">
</form>

Comment: i got error {"type":"error","message":"otp_not_found_and_placeholder_not_found_in_message"} and i have contact the support of msg91 and it said that the url not runs over post

Comment: So OTP stands for one time password. It looks like the owner of the domain you are trying to contact uses this to authenticate you.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you are not hitting an issue with CORS. Unless the resource you are hitting allows exceptions to the cross-origin policy, you will not be able to access it if your webpage is not located on control.msg91.com.

Comment: i'm using wordpress and i have done this 
function add_cors_http_header(){
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
}
add_action('init','add_cors_http_header');

Comment: i have contact the support and it says "Yes, cross domain requests are not allowed, you will need to first make the request to your server and then call the API from there." what that suppose to mean

Comment: That means you cannot directly make a POST request to another domain from your frontend browser. You will need to make a request to your website server, which is not limited by CORS, then your server will make the request and relay the response to the browser.